# Convert SQL query to linq list

Tags: c#, sql, list, linq

I'm trying to convert the next query with left joins in order to get a IList of one of my model objects.

This is the query:

```
select M.MilestoneID, MT.MilestoneTypeID, M.RCCAID
from Sourcing.MilestoneType MT
left join Sourcing.Milestone M on M.MilestoneTypeID = MT.MilestoneTypeID
where M.MilestoneID is null or (M.RCCAID = 1)
```

Output I get in SQL

```
MilestoneID | TypeID | RCCAID
------------+--------+--------
      1     |    1   |   1
    NULL    |    1   |  NULL
```

I have tried with this

```
var list  = from mt in db.MilestoneType
                        join m in db.Milestone on mt.MilestoneTypeID equals m.MilestoneTypeID
                        where m.RCCAID == id || m.MilestoneID == 0
                        select new Milestone
                        {
                            MilestoneID = m.MilestoneID,
                            RCCAID = m.RCCAID,
                            MilestoneTypeID = mt.MilestoneTypeID
                        };

            var list1 = db.MilestoneType.Join(db.Milestone,
                mt => mt.MilestoneTypeID,
                m => m.MilestoneTypeID,
                (mt, m) =>  new Milestone()
                {
                    MilestoneID = m.MilestoneID,
                    RCCAID = m.RCCAID,
                    MilestoneTypeID = mt.MilestoneTypeID
                }).Where(a => a.RCCAID == id ||a.MilestoneID==0).ToList();
```

The first one does not work.

And I get this error in the second one:

> The entity or complex type 'Model.Milestone' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

I'm trying to get all the milestone per RCCA with all the milestone types even if a milestone type is not created yet.

I expect to get an `IList<Milestone>`.

Comment: It is easier to do left join with query syntax - see my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) but in fluent syntax you need to use `GroupJoin` and `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: You cannot project to an Entity which is a part of your db context in this case Milestone...you will either need to cast to a custom class or an anonymous type..

Comment: *The first one does not work* --please explain. Note that in both cases you're doing an inner join so milestones with non-existing milestone types won't appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)